# An author of a paper included a blank supplementary file. Is it possible to make the journal correct this?

Tags: peer-review, communication, supporting-information

The authors of a paper explicitly wrote that they included their code as a supplementary file, and the file is actually available, however, it only includes the header and no code whatsoever. Is it possible to make the journal take notice and correct this issue?

Comment: Are you asking as a reviewer, or just as an interested reader?

Comment: As a reader. I want to test the methods used by the authors in my own data.

Answer (score 3):

If a file is missing or appears to be missing, then the editor in charge of the paper should obviously be notified, since he or she is the person responsible for managing communications between the authors and the reviewers. (I have done this before when there was an obvious missing document.)

Comment: Well, the file is available for download but seems to have been left blank intentionally.

Comment: @Lumimoto: "Never attribute to malice that which can be adequately explained by stupidity."  I would proceed under the assumption that it is a mistake that the editors/authors will happily correct when they are informed about it.  Why would the authors write that the code is included if they didn't intend to do so?  If the authors really don't want to share the code, you are out of luck anyway; see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/96356/can-one-demand-to-see-code-used-to-generate-an-article/96358#96358.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an old or a new paper - if it is old you may not be the first and, effectively, it won’t happen, but if new, you may be lucky...

Of course, it could be a new paper and they have changed their minds, which leaves you the choices of finding the code elsewhere or coding it yourself...

Comment: Obviously the suggestion to produce the code yourself is not well received...